# Efficiently finding the segment that has undergone changes recently in a Docx File

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am developing an application which takes the Back Up of Docx file. For the Initial Back Up I copy the entire file in the destination, but next time I want to perform an incremental Back Up i.e I want to backup only that segment of the Docx file that has undergone changes. I need to find the most efficient to do the same.
I would really be thankful if I get any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The **DOCX** file is different from the previous Microsoft Word programs, which use the file extension **DOC**, in the sense that whereas a DOC file uses a text or binary format for storing a document, a DOCX file is based on **XML** and uses **ZIP** compression for a smaller file size. In other words, a DOCX file is a set of XML files that have been compressed using ZIP.

It might help if you can use [ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) to dissect and tell which file is really changed and then incrementally save only the changes in your VCS.

Comment: I have read a docxfile using zip (PK structure) and stored the chunks(PK to PK) of bytes on network location. Also calcualted the md5 hash on the chunk and saved in hashtable. Now i modified the same docx file by adding some text at the end and saved it as new file. I used the same instance of my application and read the newly created file using same PK Chunk and comparing the newly created md5 with old. But i could only find 2 duplicate chunks out of many.

Is there any other thing which i need to consider for dedupe?